# Opening question mark only shown on some linux environment

Tags: html, linux, utf-8, virtual-machine

I'm developing an html page and it's in spanish, so i need to use "¿" (opening question mark) and i have to do it on a linux environment. However i'm editing this html docs on windows while using VirtualBox with an ubuntu server to deploy it. 
The problem is that when i use the VM, the question mark is shown, while when i try it on an actual linux OS it isn't.

On the header i have:

```
< meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

and on the body I have:

```
< p class="question">¿Cuántos grupos diferentes de < code>< var>NUM_TAKEN< /var>< /code> < var>THING< /var> puede llevar en su bolso?< /p>
```

i thought the utf-8 would solved the problem,
Any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about escaping your "special char" with the HTML representation.
In your case:

```
&iquest;
```

According to the UTF-8 problem:
Did you save your file UTF-8 encoded. Your special characters could get destroyed if you save your files with a wrong encoding.